# Django Channels ошибка Error during WebSocket

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, channels

Подскажите как настроить channels для django

https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html - всё делал как тут(в документации).

По факту получаю ошибку при загрузке страницы в консоли

```
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Как устранить данное неудобство.

```
# consumers.py
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
import json

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data = json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

Роуты в директории приложения

```
from django.urls import re_path

from .consumers import ChatConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'/$', ChatConsumer),
]
```

Роуты в директории проекта

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import apps.dialogs.routing.websocket_urlpatterns

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            apps.dialogs.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

Файл настроек

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'bcode_system.routing.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Код 404 означает, что адрес по которому вы пытаетесь подключиться не существует.

Comment: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200 - поправил роуты, вот такая ошибка теперь.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите свой код. Не исключайте возможность своей ошибки/опечатки. К тому же, так у Вас будет больше шансов получить ответ.

Comment: Отредактировал.